# NancyFX: batch requests support

Tags: c#, nancy, batching

The problem is simple: I need add batch requests support for NancyFX.

Recently I found [issue on github](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/796) about Nancy batching support. The issue was created a long time ago, but there is still no any working solution. And this issue - is the ONLY mention about Nancy batching I found!

With code from [that gist](https://gist.github.com/prabirshrestha/3929230) and [that pull request](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/pull/798) we can parse batch request to parts, and create Nancy Request objects. And we can even send them to NancyEngine.

```
var contentType = new ContentType(Request.Headers.ContentType);
var multipartRequest = new HttpMultipart(Request.Body, contentType.Boundary);

foreach (var boundry in multipartRequest.GetBoundaries())
{
    var subRequest = boundry.Value.ReadAsRequest(); // our extension

    nancyEngine.HandleRequest(subRequest,
        context =>
        {
            // success
        },
        exception =>
        {
            // error
        });
}
```

But I had troubles with creating batch response from multiple Nancy responses. I need something like `MultipartContent` class from ASP WebApi, but for Nancy.

Does anyone know any working Nancy batching solution? Or can help with creating batch response from multiple Nancy responses?